# How to use Google Place Add in Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-places-api

I'm using Google Place API for **Web Service**, in Python.
And I'm trying to add places like [the tutorial here](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places)

My code is here:

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang, GooglePlacesError, GooglePlacesAttributeError

API_KEY = "[Google Place API KEY]"
google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)

try:
    added_place = google_places.add_place(
        name='Mom and Pop local store',
        lat_lng={'lat': 51.501984, 'lng': -0.141792},
        accuracy=100,
        types=types.TYPE_HOME_GOODS_STORE,
        language=lang.ENGLISH_GREAT_BRITAIN)

except GooglePlacesError as error_detail:
    print error_detail
```

But I kept getting this error:
[image: error]

I tried to change the input into Json format or Python dictionary format, then it gave the error "google_places.add_place() only accept 1 parameter, 2 give"......

Is there any right way to use Google Place API **Add Place method** in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, finally I found the solution, it's so simple... I am not familiar with Python POST requests, in fact everything is easy.

Just need the code here, and we will be able to add a Place in Google Place API, with Python:

```
import requests

post_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=" + [YOUR_API_KEY]

r = requests.post(post_url, json={
  "location": {
    "lat": -33.8669710,
    "lng": 151.1958750
  },
  "accuracy": 50,
  "name": "Google Shoes!",
  "phone_number": "(02) 9374 4000",
  "address": "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont, NSW 2009, Australia",
  "types": ["shoe_store"],
  "website": "http://www.google.com.au/",
  "language": "en-AU"
})
```

To check the results:

```
print r.status_code
print r.json()
```